# pyzotero update fields in bulk

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am relatively new to Python, with slightly more that a year of programming experience with R.

I am trying to write code that helps me update specific fields in my Zotero library so that they conform to citation standards.

I noticed that the `author` field in Zotero can be mapped to various items in the dictionary object.

```
from pyzotero import zotero as z

zot = z.Zotero(library_id, library_type, api_key, preserve_json_order=True)

zot.collections()

song_historiography=zot.collection_items('GLN5VY3Z')

x=int()
song_historiography[x]['data']['creators']
```

By varying the values of `x`, I get to see the different data structures under which an author's name is stored.

```
[{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': '舒仁輝'}]

[{'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'On Cho', 'lastName': 'Ng'},
 {'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'Q. Edward', 'lastName': 'Wang'}]

[{'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'Peter K.', 'lastName': 'Bol'},
 {'creatorType': 'editor',
  'firstName': 'Dieter Kuhn',
  'lastName': 'Helga Stahl'}]
```

How do we access the `name`, `firstName` and `lastName` fields for the collection as a whole (collectively and/or separately) so that changes can be made to them directly via code?

Answer (score 1):

I think `DataFrame` of `pandas` is good solution for you.

```
import pandas as pd
```

First of all, I merged data seperated in 1 list.

```
data = [
        [{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': '舒仁輝'}],
        [{'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'On Cho', 'lastName': 'Ng'},
         {'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'Q. Edward', 'lastName': 'Wang'}],
        [{'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'Peter K.', 'lastName': 'Bol'},
         {'creatorType': 'editor', 'firstName': 'Dieter Kuhn', 'lastName': 'Helga Stahl'}]
       ]

authors = []
for d in data: authors += d
print (authors)
```

```
[{'creatorType': 'author', 'name': '舒仁輝'}, {'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'On Cho', 'lastName': 'Ng'}, {'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'Q. Edward', 'lastName': 'Wang'}, {'creatorType': 'author', 'firstName': 'Peter K.', 'lastName': 'Bol'}, {'creatorType': 'editor', 'firstName': 'Dieter Kuhn', 'lastName': 'Helga Stahl'}]
```

Created DataFrame from `authors`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(authors)
print (df)
```

```
  creatorType    firstName     lastName name
0      author          NaN          NaN  舒仁輝
1      author       On Cho           Ng  NaN
2      author    Q. Edward         Wang  NaN
3      author     Peter K.          Bol  NaN
4      editor  Dieter Kuhn  Helga Stahl  NaN
```

And, I made an example to set value to specific item.

```
df.at[df.name == '舒仁輝','firstName'] = 'John'
df.at[df.firstName.str.contains('Cho'), 'creatorType'] = 'editor'
print (df)
```

```
  creatorType    firstName     lastName name
0      author         John          NaN  舒仁輝
1      editor       On Cho           Ng  NaN
2      author    Q. Edward         Wang  NaN
3      author     Peter K.          Bol  NaN
4      editor  Dieter Kuhn  Helga Stahl  NaN
```

Comment: Starting from this `x=int()
song_historiography[x]['data']['creators']`, how not to merge the data manually? Also, I need a way to feed the updated data in the DataFrame back into the original dictionary so that the actual library items can be updated.

Comment: @Sati  Could you give me the output of `song_historiography[x]['data']['creators']`?

Comment: `x=int()
for x in range(len(song_historiography)): 
    song_historiography[x]['data']['creators']` yields a `KeyError: 'creators'` error. I think there are some items without the `creators` key.